# Abkürzung für "Stunde" und "Minute"

Tags: abbreviation

Gibt es Abkürzungen für *Stunde* und *Minute*?

Kann

> Dieser Film dauert 3 Stunden 5 Minuten

kürzer geschrieben werden?

Comment: Answered on http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Stunde and http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Minute

Comment: More modern than 3h5' Youtubian context 3h05m or 5m12s turns the meter to minute.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Die gebräuchlichen Abkürzungen sind:

> **Stunde:** h Std.
>   **Minute:** min Min.
>   **Sekunde:** s Sek.

Wenn man allerdings die Dauer eines Ereignisses festhalten möchte, wird man aber kaum eine Zeitangabe in der Form "2 Std. 5 Min." finden. Hier ist es üblich, entweder die Dauer in ganzen Minuten anzugeben

> Dieser Film dauert 185 min / Min.

oder die Stunden und Minuten in Anlehnung an die Urzeitangabe mit einem Doppelpunkt zu trennen. Dann wird die Zeit aber mit der Einheit *Stunden* angegeben.

> Dieser Film dauert 3:05 Std.

Comment: Der internationale, auch in Deutschland gültige, Standard (SI) ist `h` für Stunde und `min` für Minute. Die Doppelpunktschreibweise gilt ursprünglich nur für Uhrzeiten. Zeitdauern sollten also wissenschaftlich angegeben werden: `3 h 5 min` oder `185 min`. (Dezimalschreibweise ist hier ungeeignet.) [Hinweis: Der Abstand zwischen Zahl und Einheit sollte ein kleiner sein. Einen solchen habe ich auch eingegeben, aber er wird bei mir nicht als solcher dargestellt.]

Comment: @Toscho: ich habe mich gegen die wissenschaftliche Darstellung entschieden (sie aber immerhin erwähnt), weil nach der Länge eines Films gefragt wurde. Der wird selten in `h` und `min` angegeben, aber Du hast natürlich völlig recht (Dein Kommentar wäre m.E. durchaus eine weitere Antwort hier wert).

Comment: Man könnte noch folgende [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Uhrzeitangaben)-Regel erwähnen: "Aufpassen müssen Sie bei den Abkürzungen h (für Stunde) und m bzw. min (für Minute). Mit diesen Einheiten wird üblicherweise eine Zeitdauer angegeben: Eine Angabe wie z. B. 19 h 30 min bezeichnet eine Zeitdauer von neunzehn Stunden und dreißig Minuten und wird nicht als Uhrzeitangabe verwendet." Ich selbst kenne für Uhrzeiten eher die Schreibweise '7.05 Uhr' und die Doppelpunktschreibweise für eine Zeitdauer, aber ich weiß nicht, ob das eine Regel ist.

Answer (score 0):

Weil viele auf diese Frage stoßen werden, auch wenn sie nicht nach der Länge eines Filmes suchen, hier die Bemerkung von [Toscho](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2553/toscho) als Community-Antwort, damit sie nicht übersehen wird.

##### Wissenschaftliche Darstellung

> Der internationale, auch in Deutschland gültige, Standard (SI) ist `h`
> für Stunde und `min` für Minute. Die Doppelpunktschreibweise gilt
> ursprünglich nur für Uhrzeiten. Zeitdauern sollten also
> wissenschaftlich angegeben werden: `3 h 5 min` oder `185 min`.
> (Dezimalschreibweise ist hier ungeeignet.) [Hinweis: Der Abstand
> zwischen Zahl und Einheit sollte ein kleiner sein. Einen solchen habe
> ich auch eingegeben, aber er wird bei mir nicht als solcher
> dargestellt.]

##### Filmlänge meist nicht in wissenschaftlicher Darstellung

Aus der Bemerkung von [Takkat](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/23/takkat), siehe erste Anwort:

> [Die Filmlänge] wird selten in `h` und `min` angegeben.